# Google Apps Script runs successfully but events not created in Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

Do you know why this code is running itself "successfully" in Google Apps Script but the events were not created in my google calendar ?

The code :

```
function createEvents() {
  // Replace "CALENDAR_ID" with the ID of your Google Calendar
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("0150f92d506def1e40d37891011d987b3cb017e1048b796d658b8f574a700d4d@group.calendar.google.com");
  // Define start times and descriptions, the format must be "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
var startTimes = [      
new Date("  03/07/2023 11:00    "),
new Date("  03/08/2023 09:30    "),
new Date("  03/08/2023 11:00    "),
new Date("  03/08/2023 11:00    "),
new Date("  03/10/2023 09:30    "),
new Date("  03/10/2023 09:30    "),
new Date("  03/14/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  03/14/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  03/15/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  03/15/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  03/16/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  03/17/2023 10:00    "),
new Date("  03/22/2023 14:00    "),
new Date("  03/22/2023 14:00    "),
new Date("  03/22/2023 14:30    "),
new Date("  03/24/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  03/31/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  03/31/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  03/31/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  04/03/2023 10:00    "),
new Date("  04/04/2023 10:00    "),
new Date("  04/05/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  04/05/2023 10:00    "),
new Date("  04/07/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  04/07/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  04/12/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  04/12/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  04/12/2023 14:00    "),
new Date("  04/13/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  04/14/2023 08:30    "),
new Date("  04/14/2023 10:00    "),
new Date("  04/18/2023 08:30    ")
];                              
var descriptions = [        
"    US Fed Chair Powell Testimony Previous  Consensus  Forecast    ",
"    US Balance of Trade JAN Previous $-67.4B Consensus $-68.9B Forecast $-69.0B    ",
"    US JOLTs Job Openings JAN Previous 11.012M Consensus 10.5M Forecast 10.6M  ",
"    US Fed Chair Powell Testimony Previous  Consensus  Forecast    ",
"    US Unemployment Rate FEB Previous 0.034 Consensus 0.034 Forecast 0.034 ",
"    US Non Farm Payrolls FEB Previous 517K Consensus 200K Forecast 210.0K  ",
"    US Core Inflation Rate YoY FEB Previous 0.056 Consensus  Forecast  ",
"    US Inflation Rate YoY FEB Previous 0.064 Consensus  Forecast 0.062 ",
"    US PPI MoM FEB Previous 0.007 Consensus 0.003 Forecast     ",
"    US Retail Sales MoM FEB Previous 0.03 Consensus 0.002 Forecast     ",
"    US Building Permits Prel FEB Previous 1.339M Consensus  Forecast   ",
"    US Michigan Consumer Sentiment Prel MAR Previous 67 Consensus 67.5 Forecast    ",
"    US FOMC Economic Projections Previous  Consensus  Forecast     ",
"    US Fed Interest Rate Decision Previous 0.0475 Consensus  Forecast 0.05 ",
"    US Fed Press Conference Previous  Consensus  Forecast  ",
"    US Durable Goods Orders MoM FEB Previous -0.045 Consensus  Forecast    ",
"    US Core PCE Price Index MoM FEB Previous 0.006 Consensus  Forecast     ",
"    US Personal Income MoM FEB Previous 0.006 Consensus  Forecast 0.005    ",
"    US Personal Spending MoM FEB Previous  Consensus  Forecast     ",
"    US ISM Manufacturing PMI MAR Previous 47.7 Consensus  Forecast 49  ",
"    US JOLTs Job Openings FEB Previous  Consensus  Forecast    ",
"    US Balance of Trade FEB Previous  Consensus  Forecast  ",
"    US ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI MAR Previous 55.1 Consensus  Forecast 48  ",
"    US Unemployment Rate MAR Previous  Consensus  Forecast 0.037   ",
"    US Non Farm Payrolls MAR Previous  Consensus  Forecast 125K    ",
"    US Core Inflation Rate YoY MAR Previous  Consensus  Forecast 0.05  ",
"    US Inflation Rate YoY MAR Previous  Consensus  Forecast 0.06   ",
"    US FOMC Minutes Previous  Consensus  Forecast  ",
"    US PPI MoM MAR Previous  Consensus  Forecast -0.002    ",
"    US Retail Sales MoM MAR Previous  Consensus  Forecast -0.004   ",
"    US Michigan Consumer Sentiment Prel APR Previous  Consensus  Forecast  ",
"    US Building Permits Prel MAR Previous  Consensus  Forecast 1.45M   "
];                          
// Loop through the rows of data
for (var i = 0; i < startTimes.length; i++) {
// Get the end time by adding one hour to the start time
var endTime = new Date(startTimes[i].getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000));
// Create a new event on the calendar with the start and end times, and description
var event = calendar.createEvent(descriptions[i], startTimes[i], endTime);
// Add the reminders to the event
event.addPopupReminder(1440); // 1 day before
event.addPopupReminder(2880); // 2 days before
event.addPopupReminder(10080); // 1 week before
event.addPopupReminder(60); // 1 hour before
}
}
```

I am trying to create events in my Google Calendar using Google Apps Script. The code runs without any errors and the logs indicate that the execution was successful, but the events are not appearing in my calendar.

The code I'm using retrieves hard data and creates events based on that data. I've double-checked to ensure that the data is correct and that there are no missing or invalid values.

I've also checked my Google Calendar settings and confirmed that the correct calendar is selected for the events to be created in. I've tried running the code multiple times, but the same issue persists.

By the way, 1 month ago, I successfully created events in my calendar with the exact same code! (only different events)

I expected to see the events appear in my calendar after running the code, but nothing is showing up. I'm not sure what else to try or where the problem could be. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. I tested it with a calendar I own, and it worked as expected.

I would guess you are not viewing the proper calendar to confirm the event was created. The fact that you can run the code `event.create` without error means you have permission to make an edit and it's successfully being done.

To illustrate, you should log the event ID immediately after created:

`Logger.log(event.getId());`

then run another script to confirm"

`Logger.log(calendar.getEventById(???).getDescription())`;

Comment: Thanks for your help, you're right it is right. I was checking the right calendar though. But I don't why it was not creating the events. I've just created a whole new project and copy paste my code and run it again and now yes it works... very strange but at least thanks to you I knew my code was OK xD thanks